# php GD image resizing to smaller new image -> blurring problem

Tags: php

I am downscaling images from 200px wide to 190px wide, with [this class](https://web.archive.org/web/20110630134832/http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk:80/articles/php-image-resizing.php)

here is what i get[image]

img 1 = original - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - img 2 = smaller

I've tried a few different widths but i get the same loss of sharpness/blurring with all image sizes. I have quality set to 100 (max)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which method are you using imagecopyresampled or imagecopyresized? imagecopyresampled gives better results. Also consider Imagemagick library if possible: http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

Comment: im using imagecopyresampled, have updated post with missing link to the class im using..

Comment: then the only way you're going to achieve better quality is by using imagemagick as Piotr suggested

Comment: imagick looks like a real ball ache... there's no way i can improve the quality i'm getting with GD?

Answer (score 6):

I found this solution and it works for me, I've got it on my facebook wall (https://www.facebook.com/antimatterstudios/posts/10151207306454364)

a nice little tip I found online today (facebook wall has the direct link) for those people using php's GD library to resize image and finding the images are resized and blurry, you can use this little snippet of code to sharpen up the image, it's much much better

```
 function imagesharpen( $image)
 {
    $matrix = array(
      array(-1, -1, -1),
      array(-1, 16, -1),
      array(-1, -1, -1),
    );

    $divisor = array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $matrix));
    $offset = 0; 
    imageconvolution($image, $matrix, $divisor, $offset);

    return $image;
}
```

Comment: That works surprisingly well. I found tho, 16 was a little bit too sharp. 18 was more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using timthumb?

http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/source/browse/trunk/timthumb.php

Working on the same-ish problem, using this as a base.

Comment: Nope, looks interesting... Can't tell if it uses GD?

Comment: uses GD - imagecreatetruecolor() is dependent on that library.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `imagecopyresampled()` instead `imagecopyresized()` and thats it. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is bicubic resizing with GD. It takes the same arguments as standard ImageCopyResampled function.
It gives much sharper result, especially than source resolution is close to the destination resolution.
But of course, it’s much slower than standard GD, and ImageMagic gives clear the better results.

```
    function ImageCopyResampledBicubic(&$dst_image, &$src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h)  {
    // we should first cut the piece we are interested in from the source
    $src_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopy($src_img, $src_image, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);

    // this one is used as temporary image
    $dst_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($dst_w, $dst_h);

    ImagePaletteCopy($dst_img, $src_img);
    $rX = $src_w / $dst_w;
    $rY = $src_h / $dst_h;
    $w = 0;
    for ($y = 0; $y < $dst_h; $y++)  {
        $ow = $w; $w = round(($y + 1) * $rY);
        $t = 0;
        for ($x = 0; $x < $dst_w; $x++)  {
            $r = $g = $b = 0; $a = 0;
            $ot = $t; $t = round(($x + 1) * $rX);
            for ($u = 0; $u < ($w - $ow); $u++)  {
                for ($p = 0; $p < ($t - $ot); $p++)  {
                    $c = ImageColorsForIndex($src_img, ImageColorAt($src_img, $ot + $p, $ow + $u));
                    $r += $c['red'];
                    $g += $c['green'];
                    $b += $c['blue'];
                    $a++;
                }
            }
            ImageSetPixel($dst_img, $x, $y, ImageColorClosest($dst_img, $r / $a, $g / $a, $b / $a));
        }
    }

    // apply the temp image over the returned image and use the destination x,y coordinates
    imagecopy($dst_image, $dst_img, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $dst_w, $dst_h);

    // we should return true since ImageCopyResampled/ImageCopyResized do it
    return true;
}
```