# ImageMagick - what do i need to be aware of?

Tags: php, imagemagick

Even on max quality GD just wasn't good enough quality, so i'm pretty sure i'm going to have to go down the ImageMagick route... I've heard stories....!

What kind of things no i need to be careful about/aware of when using/installing ImageMagick?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I've used ImageMagick to a fair extent, with the usual minor programming problems associated with any library.

Comment: reading on S.O., alot of people seems to be warning about issues with it. like problems uninstalling, and temp file errors?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. Just download and run.

Also, I hope you have tried imagecopyresampled of GD, not the other resize function.

Comment: Good point. The `imagecopyresized` function does all sorts of fails. Why the developers even included it is beyond me.

Comment: yes i was using imagecopyresampled : my previus post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799159/php-gd-image-resizing-to-smaller-new-image-blurring-problem